# unable to generate matrix in desired format

Tags: r

I need to make a function such that it create a matrix  across two groups and provide total of the groups at row and column level, along with matrix results

```
Inputs for functions -> df
                        credit breaks
 
                        Rate_Cutpoints from 1..5
```

O/P needs to be final table provide below

MY Data Frame

```
credit <- c(10,20,30,40,10,30,50,70,90,100,25,45,67,87,98,54,34,56,78,23,45,56,12)
rate <- c(1,2,3,4,1,3,5,7,9,10,2,4,6,8,9,5,3,5,7,2,4,5,1)
Marks <- c(9,3,5,6,7,8,9,1,3,10,4,5,6,7,5,4,8,3,5,6,7,8,9)
Points <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2,3,4,4,5,7,8,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Scale <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2,3,4,4,5,7,8,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Category <- c('book', 'pen', 'textbook', 'pencil_case','book', 'pen', 'textbook', 'pencil_case','book', 'pen', 'textbook', 'pencil_case','book','pen' ,'pen', 'textbook', 'pencil_case','book', 'pen', 'textbook', 'pencil_case','book', 'pencil_case')
# Join the variables to create a data frame
df <- data.frame(credit,rate,Marks,Points,Scale,Category)
```

MY Inputs

```
credit_breaks<-c(0,15,30,45,65,75,1000)
Rate_Cutpoints1<-c(0,1,2,5,7,9,10)
Rate_Cutpoints2<-c(0,3,4,7,8,9,10)
Rate_Cutpoints3<-c(0,1,5,6,8,9,10)
Rate_Cutpoints4<-c(0,1,3,6,7,9,10)
Rate_Cutpoints5<-c(0,2,3,4,8,9,10)
Rate_Cutpoints6<-c(0,3,4,5,7,9,10)
```

MY code it basically first make credit band  column from credit breaks which is provided as input and then using that make another column as rate bands  based on rate breaks
calculate few metric and then provide metrics

```
df1<-df %>% mutate(Credit_Band = cut(credit,include.lowest = TRUE,right=TRUE,
                                     breaks =credit_breaks ,labels = FALSE))



df2<-df1 %>%
  group_by(credit) %>%
  mutate(New_Band =
           (ifelse(Credit_Band==1, (cut(rate, Rate_Cutpoints1 ,labels = FALSE)),
                   ifelse(Credit_Band==2, (cut(rate, Rate_Cutpoints2 ,labels = FALSE)),
                          ifelse(Credit_Band==3, (cut(rate, Rate_Cutpoints3 ,labels = FALSE)),
                                 ifelse(Credit_Band==4, (cut(rate, Rate_Cutpoints4 ,labels = FALSE)),
                                        ifelse(Credit_Band==5, (cut(rate, Rate_Cutpoints5,labels = FALSE)),
                                               ifelse(Credit_Band==6, (cut(rate, Rate_Cutpoints6,labels = FALSE)),
                                                      NA))))))))

df2<-as.data.frame(df2)


summary_results<-df2%>%
  group_by(Credit_Band,New_Band)%>%
  dplyr::summarize(dist = n()/nrow(df2),
                   count =n(),
                   avg_marks= sum(Marks, na.rm=TRUE),
                   sum_points = sum(Points,na.rm = TRUE),
                   sum_scale = sum(Scale,na.rm = TRUE))


summary_results$final<-summary_results$avg_marks/summary_results$sum_points 


results<-reshape2::dcast(data = summary_results,formula =  Credit_Band~New_Band,
                         value.var = "final")
```

my result o/p is  cross tab across credit and rate bands

Then below code is to calculate total across credit and rate bands

```
total_rows_value=df2%>% group_by(New_Band)%>% 
  dplyr::summarize(sum_points = sum(Points ,na.rm = TRUE),
                   avg_marks= sum(Marks, na.rm=TRUE),
  )

total_rows_value$final<-total_rows_value$avg_marks/total_rows_value$sum_points 


total_cols_vals=df2%>% group_by(Credit_Band)%>% 
  dplyr::summarize(sum_points = sum(Points ,na.rm = TRUE),
                   avg_marks= sum(Marks, na.rm=TRUE),
  )

total_cols_vals$final<-total_cols_vals$avg_marks/total_cols_vals$sum_points
```

Now MY above O/P needs to be clubbed in a fashion to generate below matrix  as Final O/P desired

```
Credit_Band              1      2        3        4          5          6       TotalCols
               1      1.78      NA      NA        NA        NA          NA.       1.79
               2      1.44      NA      NA        NA        NA          NA.       1.44
               3       NA    1.23       NA        NA        NA          NA.       1.24
               4       NA       NA.     1         NA        NA          NA        1
               5       NA       NA      NA      0.58       NA           NA        0.58
               6       NA       NA      NA      1.25      0.83          1         0.93
Total_R               1.59.   1.24      1.      0.75.     0.83.         1
```

Comment: are you wanting an object for presentation; i.e. I want to show someone a pretty table laid out like this, or are you wanting an object to further compute on ? If the former, there are a myriad of pretty table printers, we could choose one and help you combine your elements to look nice. if the latter, you should acknowledge that a matrix is a rectangular object with no holes and of a single data type (i.e. you cant have a gap in the bottom right corner, it would have to be NA if the data is numeric)

Comment: p.s. not attempting to address your overall issue before you respond to my comment, but I would replace your df2 creation step with something like `library(glue) ; df2 <- df1 %>%   rowwise() %>% mutate(New_Band = cut(rate,get(x = glue("Rate_Cutpoints{Credit_Band}")),labels = FALSE   ))`

Comment: so I need to make it a function which could be used multiple times for different computation and get the final results as the final o/p 
we can keep it  NA or 0 for now the bottom right and the fields will be numeric

Comment: So the final matrix is the o/p and then I need to generate similar matrix for diff inputs , which I will copy to excel and share in ppt

Answer (score 1):

```
(results_body <- results[,-1])
(results_rownames <- results[,1])



(fin <- cbind(
  rbind(results_body,total_rows_value$final),
  totcol = c(total_cols_vals$final,NA)))

rownames(fin) <-c(results_rownames,"Total_R")
```

```
> round(fin,2)
           1    2  3    4    5  6 totcol
1       1.79   NA NA   NA   NA NA   1.79
2       1.44   NA NA   NA   NA NA   1.44
3         NA 1.24 NA   NA   NA NA   1.24
4         NA   NA  1   NA   NA NA   1.00
5         NA   NA NA 0.58   NA NA   0.58
6         NA   NA NA 1.25 0.83  1   0.94
Total_R 1.59 1.24  1 0.75 0.83  1     NA
```

Comment: total rows results are used from from separate logic

Comment: dont understand your comment, can you use more words to say it ?

Comment: Sry you are correct ,  I have one more query as to how could I use the cut provides as input for function  for example  function(df, credit_breaks, Rate_Cutpoints1, Rate_Cutpoints2, Rate_Cutpoints3, Rate_Cutpoints4, Rate_Cutpoints5, Rate_Cutpoints6)

The Rate_Cutpoints6 and other are not able to use as function inputs